# Changing the Default Currency in Siebel Applet,

Tags: siebel

I have a simple requirement to change the default currency in Siebel from USD.

I have already changed the default currency for the Organization , but when creating new amount figures via an applet the default currency is still USD,

The field uses the

> Currency Popup Applet

which in turns has the pick list

> Currency Pick Applet

.

WIll like to change the default value from USD.
It will help making the application easily usable for financial complaint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a field called [Currency Code] in your bc, which predefaults to System:Currency.  Try changing that predefault, so you get a different code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, just tested it on my sample ..works perfectly